# jquery global variable accesibilty

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create a **global variable** to get the initial position of a div,which can be accessed out all function even in

```
$(document).bind('click', function (e) {
```

Or can the below function

```
$(document).bind('click', function (e) { //blahblah });
```

be accessed inside the

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

Comment: declare the variable outside document.ready.

Comment: Declaring a variable globally can be accessed in all methods and functions!

Comment: Better to just create a function to retrieve the object's position anytime you need it.  It doesn't cost much to get the position so just get it on demand.   I see no reason to use a global for this.

Comment: @Anoop Joshi:can we declare a variable outside doc.ready??

Comment: @NMN yes you can, declaring a variable has nothing to do with DOM

Comment: Something like this.http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/39/

Comment: You can check this (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) in order to understand the javascript scope

Comment: var initPos  = $("#fixed_contact_us").position(); added before doc.ready but value defined to undefined

Comment: Global variables are a sign of code smell; where possible, you should avoid creating them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a variable outside of document.ready or attach it to window object.

```
var globalVariable;
$(document).ready(function(){
     globaVariable = $("div").offset().top;
    // set the position of div as you desire

});
```

else use `window.globalVariable`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     window.globaVariable = $("div").offset().top;
    // set the position of div as you desire

});
```

Comment: Use `window.globalVariable` or `globalVariable`  just inside the click event handler. It will be available

Answer (score 2):

In this case you don't actually need a global variable at all; just declare it inside your document ready event handler:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // declared in this scope
    var initPos = $("#fixed_contact_us").position();

    $(document).bind('click', function (e) { 
        // initPos is accessible here, too.
        console.log(initPos);
    });
});

// initPos is not available here
```

It's recommended to keep your global space as clean as possible and properly scope your variables.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred and most cross browser compatible way to handle this would be to assign it to the window object.

```
window.initialPosition = '';
```

You can then access this value within the current scope of the page by calling `window.initialPosition`. You can read more about variable scope [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variable_scope).

Answer (score 1):

Either create a variable outside of all functions, to declare as a global variable

```
<script>
var globalVar
function foo() {
  ...
}
</script>
```

or assign to a property on window, because in browsers, all global variables are properties of the window object

```
<script>
function foo() {
  window.globalVar = ...;
}
</script>
```